# UITabBar - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

Is there any way how I can create a UITabBar with options such as Home, Search and Login and display these on all the pages including those without a UITabBarItem? For instance, on my Shopping Cart view I will have the UITabBar (with Home, Search and Login) but without a UITabBarItem for the Shopping Cart?

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate an UITabBar using custom UIButtons.

I'm using this technique in an app I'm developing at the moment because I want certain effects (like fading) when switching between different views.

Answer (score 1):

[UITabBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (you should carefully read the doc) extends UIView.

So :

- You can put it wherever you want ([addSubview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#jumpTo_51) method)
- You can change items in run time with

> -(void)setItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated